# Nginx ignores root directive (different from global) in a location block

Tags: nginx

I am trying to add html form and javascript file which send post request. I placed it in dicrectory different from my front end (written in angular).

Here is the nginx confg.

```
server {
listen 80;
real_ip_header X-Forwarded-For;
set_real_ip_from 127.0.0.1;
server_name localhost;

root /var/www/html/psycho-test-rest/psycho_front/dist;

location /download_report/ {
root /var/www/html/psycho-test-rest/psycho_front/user-results;
try_files $uri /resultsdownload.html;
}

location ~ ^/(tests|CRUD)/ {
include uwsgi_params;
uwsgi_pass unix:/var/www/html/psycho-test-rest/socket.sock;
uwsgi_modifier1 30;
}

error_page 404 =200 /index.html;
location = /404.html {
root /usr/share/nginx/html;
}

error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
location = /50x.html {
root /usr/share/nginx/html;
}
}
```

I am trying to make nginx return `resultsdownload.html` in the first directive, but file is always not found as root directory in location block is always replaced by global root. Here is the error from error.log.

```
2018/06/19 05:21:59 [error] 26553#26553: *6 open() "/var/www/html/psycho-test-rest/psycho_front/dist/user-results/resultsdownload.html" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 212.XXX.XXX.XXX, server: localhost, request: "GET /user-results/resultsdownload.html HTTP/1.1", host: "188.XXX.XXX.XXX"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last element of a `try_files` directive is a URI, a response code or a named location. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for details.

The URI `/resultsdownload.html` is not processed by the `location /download_report/` block, and therefore does not use the `root` value defined within that block.

Either define a `location` to process the the `/resultsdownload.html` URI, for example:

```
location = /resultsdownload.html { 
    root /var/www/html/psycho-test-rest/psycho_front/user-results; 
}
```

Or, use a *file* parameter in the `try_files` statement, for example, by adding a response code as the final parameter:

```
try_files $uri /resultsdownload.html =404;
```